# Get wikitext from wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm looking at the API documentation here,

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query

Getting the wikitext for a page is mentioned in the beginning of the documentation,

> The action=query module allows you to get information about a wiki and the data stored in it, such as the wikitext of a particular page, the links and categories of a set of pages, or the token you need to change wiki content.

but I cant seem to figure out what parameters to pass in the API request to return the wikitext for a given page.  Anyone know how to do this?

I've tried parameters like,

```
{'action':'query', 'titles':'Anarchism', 'prop':'wikitext', 'format':'json'}
```

Comment: I've tried this query. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&formatversion=2&titles=Anarchism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use this query       .

```
   https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Anarchism&rvslots=main
```